# Extend time depending on working days per week

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to build dynamic time schedule with function, that will take in consideration how many days/week will be working days.

[image]

All lighter green cells are changeable, user inputs data in there. White color cell with header END is calculated. My current formula is located in Column `END` (it is affecting bar) and result should be:

1. As it is 5 working days/week bar should be until Mo 18
2. As it is 6 working days/week bar should be until We 13
3. As it is 7 working days/week bar should be until Su 10

I don't think this is much help, but as rules are requiring to post what has been tried yet, here it is:

```
IF(G10>6;D10+F10-1;IF(G10<=5;(D10+F10-1)+CEILING((F10/7);1)*2;(D10+F10)+CEILING((F10/7);1)
```

- G10 = WD/W
- D10 = START
- E10 = END
- F10 = DAYS

How it should be edited to work correct?

Comment: It will give me working days in specified time range? I am currently specifying working days per week myself.

Comment: How do you know which days of the week you will not be working when it is less than 5?  when its 6 days a week which day are you not working?

Comment: If it is 5 then Mo-Fr, if it is 6 then Mo-Sa, if it is 7 then Mo-Su

Comment: will it ever be less than 5?

Comment: No, there will be number 5,6 or 7, but `D10+F10-1` formula is actually covering all possible variants if it is 7 working days a week. I need to extend time schedule if it is 5 or 6 working days a week. I have tried to count DAYS/7 to get weeks number, then to add + days for each week but my logic seems not to work

Comment: Will your start date always be a monday?

Comment: No I can input there whatever day. in START field. It just a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no holidays, you can use the following formula in E10 and copy down:

```
=(D10+IF(WEEKDAY(D10,2)>G10,8-WEEKDAY(D10,2),0))+F10+((ROUNDUP((F10+((WEEKDAY((D10+IF(WEEKDAY(D10,2)>G10,8-WEEKDAY(D10,2),0)),2))-1))/G10,0)-1)*(7-G10))-1
```

[image: POC]

In column H I used a COUNTIF function to count the number X's in order to verify the right number of days were represented.

Comment: Fixed the formula now working for Saturday and Start dates when they are non working days by moving them the following Monday.  Tested with every day of the week for start day and tested with 21 and 20 working days.